# Compatibility for old Sram 7-speed shifter

Tags: shifter, sram, compatibility, 7-speed

A buddy asked me to fix his bike. The shifter is broken. It's an older bike with a Sram SRT300i-71 shifter. I found an exact match on that is [fairly cheap on ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Sram-SRT300-Shifter-21-speed-New-Old-Stock-/160998850301?_trksid=m263&_trkparms=algo=SIC&its=I&itu=UCI%252BIA%252BUA%252BFICS%252BUFI&otn=21&pmod=110993485215&ps=50), but I also found a [similar model](http://www.rei.com/product/737410/sram-mrx-comp-set-twist-shifter-7-speed) on REI for even cheaper. I was wondering if this or any other newer 7-speed Sram shifter would be compatible. I'm not super familiar with older model shifters like these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Just checked an old copy of Sutherland's Handbook for Bicycle Mechanics (6th edition), and the SRT300i is actually Shimano-compatible, pulling 2:1 ratio. I've updated the comment below to correct that mistake.

Many SRAM shifters, are only compatible with SRAM ["1:1 Actuation"](http://www.sram.com/sram/mountain/technologies/1..1)* derailleurs. Shimano shifters and derailleurs use a "2:1" ratio of cable pull to actuation - the MRX you linked to at REI is one of the few SRAM models that are designed to be Shimano-compatible, like the SRT300i you have now.

(The SRAM ratio is actually closer to 1.1:1, while the Shimano ratio is about 1.7:1, but the common terminology rounds these values. The spacing between cogs in 7- and 8-speed systems is 5mm. In practice, this means that one click of a SRAM shifter pulls about 4.5mm of cable to move the shifter over 5mm, while each click of a Shimano-compatible shifter pulls only 2.9mm of cable to do the same.)